# error in inheritance c++ using swig

Tags: python, c++, swig

i have a have a c++ code that is been wrapped by swig and used by python.
i want to create a way to run a callback python code inside the c++ code.
so i'v created a "abstract" class (it's not abstract yet) and i'm sublassing it in c++ inside the .i file.

here is some code snippet that i wrote

.h file

```
class Listener {
public:
    Listener();
    virtual void register_new();
    virtual void run(Msg &m);
    virtual ~Listener();
};
```

.i file

```
%feature("director") PyListener;
using namespace std;
%{
#include "../core/listener.h"
%}

%include "../core/listener.h"

class PyListener : public Listener {
    PyObject * function;
public:
    PyListener() {};
    PyListener(PyObject * func) : function(func) {};
    void register_new() {Py_XINCREF(function);};
    ~PyListener () {Py_XDECREF(function);};
     void run(Msg &m) {
        PyGILState_STATE gstate;
        gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();
        PyObject *pValue = PyCObject_FromVoidPtr((void*)&m,NULL);
        PyObject *pArgs = PyTuple_New(1);
        PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, pValue);
        PyObject_CallObject(function, pArgs);
        PyGILState_Release(gstate);
    };
};
```

but during compilation a get

```
/bin/sh ../../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I. -I./../core -I./../../../include -I/opt/regression/usr/include/ -I./../../include_dep/ -I/usr/include/python2.6  -fPIC    -g -O2 -MT sim_wrap.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/sim_wrap.Tpo -c -o sim_wrap.lo sim_wrap.cxx
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I. -I./../core -I./../../../include -I/opt/regression/usr/include/ -I./../../include_dep/ -I/usr/include/python2.6 -fPIC -g -O2 -MT sim_wrap.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/sim_wrap.Tpo -c sim_wrap.cxx  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/sim_wrap.o
sim_wrap.cxx: In function ‘PyObject* _wrap_new_PyListener__SWIG_0(PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
sim_wrap.cxx:36391: error: ‘PyListener’ was not declared in this scope
sim_wrap.cxx:36391: error: ‘result’ was not declared in this scope
sim_wrap.cxx:36394: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
sim_wrap.cxx:36394: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘new’
...
```

Comment: Is the `python-dev` / `python-devel` package installed on this system?

Comment: yes of course, if i remove this listener part i can compile and use other swig functions defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're both declaring and defining a new class at the same time you need to enclose that inside `%inline` within the SWIG interface, e.g.

```
%inline %{
    class PyListener : public Listener {
        PyObject * function;
    public:
        PyListener() {};
        PyListener(PyObject * func) : function(func) {};
        void register_new() {Py_XINCREF(function);};
        ~PyListener () {Py_XDECREF(function);};
         void run(Msg &m) {
            PyGILState_STATE gstate;
            gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();
            PyObject *pValue = PyCObject_FromVoidPtr((void*)&m,NULL);
            PyObject *pArgs = PyTuple_New(1);
            PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, pValue);
            PyObject_CallObject(function, pArgs);
            PyGILState_Release(gstate);
        };
    };
%}
```

This causes SWIG to not only wrap the type, but pass the declaration/definition through to the generated C++ code as well. That's needed because `PyListener` is specific to your SWIG interface so isn't known in any of your other header files.

Comment: thanks!
i have another small question if you can help
in my python code i do the flowing:
py_sim = bms.PyListener(func)
ms_node.setCallBack(py_sim)
and then i leave this function and swig thinks that py_sim is no longer used so he deletes it
and then the c++ code crashs
i tried playing with newobject derective with no luck

Comment: @rafiwiener Aren't you better off storing the module & function as char* instead? Something like: `cb = PyObject_GetAttrString( module, function); PyObject* result = PyObject_CallObject(cb, args);`

Comment: @sambha whats the advantage of doing that over my implementation?

Comment: @rafiwiener I am just trying to see if the crash can be avoided. I cannot envision all that you are doing. I have a similar callback setup but I do the func pointer extraction in my C code (from python I pass strings for module.function) than passing the python function obj. Also I see Py_XINCREF in register_new & you have to explicitly call it. Should it be done in the c'tor instead?

Comment: i need to call the incref so python won't destroy this object.
i see no reason why to cast it to char and then back to pyobject
to avoid the crash i add the holder of the py object to the class that calls it as an attribute then swig doesn't delete it.
the right way to handle this is to call the __disown()__ method but i couldn't find the way to call it